# How to access a variable in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I have a Controller Action method which takes a nullable integer parameter representing a number of nights:

```
public ActionResult Comfort(int? numberNights)
{
     ViewBag.Message = "Price from"+numberNights + " nights";
     return View();
}
```

And I have a corresponding Razor View, which displays rooms and their price based on the room cost per night and the number of nights chosen.

```
@model Room
@foreach (Room room in Model)
{
    <p>Number room: @room.NumberRoom </p>
    <p>Cost per Night:  @room.CostPerNight</p>
}
```

How can I access the argument `numberNights` that is passed to the `Comfort` method, from from this View, for example:

```
<p>Cost per numberNights Nights:  (@room.CostPerNight * numberNights)</p>
```

Comment: Unclear what you asking. Is the view you have shown generated by the `Comfort()` method? What is the model (and why does `Room` have a property `IEnumerable<Room>`)?

Comment: Updated the language in the question to make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Set numberNights in ViewBag (at controller) like

```
@ViewBag.NumberNights = numberNights;
```

Then use it in the view like

```
@{
   var numberNights = Convert.ToInt32(ViewBag.NumberNights);
 }
```

After that use it anywhere you want like

```
<p>Cost per numberNights Nights:  (@room.CostPerNight * @numberNights)</p>
```

Comment: @Askert, add var before **numberNights** in second part. By the way, i update answer. check it.

Comment: good!Thanks! And what display result of the operation multiply? Because now I have display :  ( 150*10) ;    150 - Cost 10 - Nights

Comment: try this `@room.CostPerNight.ToString() * @numberNights.ToString() = @(room.CostPerNight * numberNights)`